# view animations

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, core-animation

I'm trying to add a sub view with Core-Animation using the attached code.
First time it happens as expected, but after that there's a flash of white in the place of the sub-view before it's fully pushed.

```
// Add the picker
viewToPush.frame = CGRectMake(0,185,320, 258);

CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];

[self.view addSubview:viewToPush];
[viewToPush.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

btw, in order to remove the subView I just use

```
[viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
```

10x

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add the animation to the `viewToPush`'s layer, not the super view's? I suspect the layer of `viewToPush` is not stable as you remove the view from the super view. Do you have many views that can act as `viewToPush` or `viewToRemove` so they have to be dynamically allocated? Otherwise I would just change their hidden properties to implement such animations.